# How to create a css-only slide-down animation (using JS only to manage toggling state)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a sliding animation only using CSS.
JavaScript is used just to toggle the open/close state of the element.

I can use `translated` and `rotateX` CSS transforms to hide/show the menu. But those techniques do not reduce/increase the height of the element, and thus the parent does not follow the children height.

I want to be able to slide up/down an element inside its parent, while the parent also collapses and expands. And I want to do this using transitions so that a sliding-up/down animation would be shown.

```js
var slideMenu = document.querySelector("#slideMenu");
var slide = document.querySelector("#slide");
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (slideMenu.classList.contains("open")) {
    slideMenu.classList.remove("open");
  } else {
    slideMenu.classList.add("open");
  }
});
```

```css
.open {
  background: red;
}

#parent {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <button id="slide">sldie</button>
  <div id="slideMenu">
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
    <div>item 3</div>
    <div>item 4</div>
    <div>item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem", where it notes, "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so—**but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript/HTML/CSS."

Answer (score 0):

add a class to open and close then toggle the class with js
using `yourclass.classList.toggle(classname)`
your updated sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-benji-boil1b?file=/index.html

Comment: In your example, parent element is not expanding/collapsing with the menu. I need that to happen

Comment: This is a link to an answer, not an answer itself. Just because a question lacks sufficient code in the question itself is no reason not to supply sufficient code in an answer (or, indeed, it does provide a reason to not answer the question at all).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a transform: translate and change layout of navbar

```js
var slideMenu = document.querySelector("#slideMenu");
var slide = document.querySelector("#slide");
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (slideMenu.classList.contains("open")) {
    slideMenu.classList.remove("open");
  } else {
    slideMenu.classList.add("open");
  }
});
```

```css
#parent {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#slide {
  background: gray;
  z-index: 30;
  position: relative;
}

#slideMenu {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 1s transform ease-in;
  position: relative;
}

#slideMenu.open {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="slide">
    <button>sldie</button>
  </div>
  <div id="slideMenu">
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
    <div>item 3</div>
    <div>item 4</div>
    <div>item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example, parent element is not expanding/collapsing with the menu. I need that to happen